# DataTables: filter search rows + child rows

Tags: search, filter, datatables, row

http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

See in this example as you type in the search field it automatically filters matching rows. But how do I include the child rows within these rows in the filter search as well?

For example if I want to find an extension number that's stored within the record.

Answer (score 0):

Use `table.rows().nodes()`.

Reference: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19158/how-to-search-through-the-child-row-datatables-1-10